# location based data grabbing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, java-me, geolocation

I have to develop an algorithm for location based data grabbing and displaying it on a mobile device. I'm just a web programmer with some knowledge of php and mysql. I need to develop this algorithm. Please give some instructions on where to start the development.

Comment: can you please describe what you want to do functionally

Comment: i want to fetch the data that needed by a user depending on his location , for example let's say the person want to find the ATM machines around him within a 100m radius, so the user can search for that and algorithm will show the ATM machines depending on his location , that is the kind of thing that i want to implement.

Comment: @anganMIT please update your question according to that comment, in order for answers to come more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have PointOfInterest table that relates to address.
Let say I want to find an ATM in Chicago. Then you perform a seach for all ATMs in chicago.
After you get your result set you perform distance calculation over each of them and check which is the closest one.

Here you may find a way how to calculate distance based on longitude/latitude coordinates

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html